# Do I have to move a tracking dot for each frame?

Tags: tracking

I have recently started using Blenders Motion Tracking. Sometimes one tracking dot is in the incorrect position for many frames, even though the camera doesn't move at that point. Do I need to move it to the correct position for each frame, or can I move them all to the same place ?

Comment: You can move it for one frame, and then track it forward and hope it stays in the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play the clip from the beginning, and at the first “sign of trouble“ where the tracking marker is not in its right position, stop the playback, find the exact first frame of the trouble, then move the tracking marker back where it supposed to be. Then re-track it forward from there. If it seems to be very unstable, you can track it for one frame at a time instead of to the end of the clip.